# C++: Is there a way to specify a generalized class that inherits from another?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Vec
{
    double dim[];
public:
    Vec(void);
    ~Vec(void);
    virtual void Add(Vec vector) = 0;

};
```

I want to replace the `Vec` in `Vec::Add()` with "any class that inherits from `Vec`".
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the parameter to a reference to const Vec:

```
virtual void Add(Vec const &vector) = 0;
```

A class (publicly) derived from `Vec` can be passed by reference to the base class.

Also, since you apparently plan to use `Vec` as a base class, you probably want to make its dtor virtual too. Otherwise, if you attempt to destroy an object of the derived type via a pointer or reference to the base, you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: "error C2503: 'Vec' : base classes cannot contain zero-sized arrays"  Why is this? (This is after I inherited from it)

Comment: @NBcode: You need to specify the size of `dim`, as in: `double dim[10];` If you don't know the size up-front (or probably even if you do) you almost certainly want to use `std::vector<double> dim;` instead.

Comment: I made a Vec3 class, which inherits from Vec. Is it possible to force the parameter in the override Add() method to be a "Vec3"?

Comment: @NBcode: Not really, no. You can define an `Add` that takes a reference to a Vec3, but it will *not* be an override of the base `Add` -- it'll just hide the base class function.

Answer (score 2):

Use const reference to Vec, or a pointer to Vec

```
class Vec
{
    double dim[];
public:
    virtual void Add(const Vec& vector) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you pass a pointer or a reference to a `Vec`:

```
 class Vec
{
    double dim[];
public:
    Vec(void);
    ~Vec(void);
    virtual void Add(Vec* vector) = 0;

};
```

Conversion from a pointer to a `class` that derives from `Vec` to a `Vec*` is implicit.

If you pass by value, you run into object slicing and the behavior won't be what you expect.